# How do you use the powered minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

since the v1.6, powered minecarts (or minecart with furnace) no longer pushes other minecarts.

I was counting on this to push other chess minecarts and myself from one end to another.

How do you guys to do move a set of chest minecart around? Do we have to use boosters and set them on the track one after the other?

I wish I could make a more train-like option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear that this is a bug. For example, they will work fine if you put them on a track in the other direction. (If I recall correctly, minecarts collide correctly on north-south track and pass through/stop on any other.)

I recommend waiting for a bug fix or using lots of [Powered Rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail) if you have the gold. You don't need every rail to be powered for moving empty/chest minecarts; every other tile is sufficient for a diagonal slope, and up to, oh, about 16 apart should be fine on the flat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It might be out of subject now but i haven't been able to use boosters on a 45 degree slope. meaning I would need to do a lot of digging and flatten the track every 16 tracks which would make my "landing" a lot further than planned.

Is there a way to use boosters on a 45 degre slope?

Comment: @nde I think when he says "diagonal slope" he means a 45 degree slope.

Comment: I have a spiraling track with powered rails on the slopes: powered slope, powered slope, plain slope, turn, repeat. This works fine and is quite fast.

Comment: Awesome :) I'll consider something like this !